# jquery slide text from right to left after div height reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

so im trying to slide my text from right to left using a sort of work around by just sliding the div. Its supposed to slide when the user has scrolled down to the div height and trigger the slide.

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>     $(window).scroll(function() {
>         var top = $(this).scrollTop();
>         var aTop = $('.right-slide').height();
>         if(top >= aTop){
>             $(this).animate({right:'+=100%', opacity:'1'},1000);
>         }
>     });
> });
> ```

and the css as

> .right-slide {
>       right: -100%;
>       display: block;
>       opacity: 0.5;
>       position: relative;
>   }

and html as

> ```
> <section id="about" class="about">
>     <div class="container">
>         <div class="row">
>             <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
>                 <h2>About Me</h2>
>                 <hr class="small">
>                 <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite. <br> 
>                     Morbi nulla est, molestie varius porta non, pharetra </p> 
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         <div class="row spacer">
>             <div class="col-lg-4">
>                 <h3 class="thicker left-slide">Name</h3h3>
>                 <h4 class="left-slide">Jeremiah Mejia</h4>
>                 <h3 class="spacer left-slide thicker">Date of Birth</h3>
>                 <h4 class="left-slide">1 July 1991</h4>
>                 <h3 class="spacer left-slide thicker">Birth Place</h3>
>                 <h4 class="left-slide">New Zealand</h4>
>             </div>
>             <div class="col-lg-4 fade text-center">
>                 <img src="img/rsz_1dsc_0035.jpg" class="img-circle ">   
>             </div>
>             <div class="col-lg-4 ">
>                 <h3 class="thicker right-slide">City</h3>
>                 <h4 class="right-slide">Auckland, New Zealand</h4>
>                 <h3 class="spacer right-slide thicker">Email</h3>
>                 <h4 class="right-slide">fwaswf.fwasd@ymail.com</h4>
>                 <h3 class="spacer right-slide thicker">Contact Number</h3>
>                 <h4 class="right-slide">123 145 6789</h4>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         <div class="row spacer">
>             <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
>                 <p>
>                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas libero nulla, tristique a neque a, pharetra iaculis justo. Duis velit purus, volutpat ac nulla at, dapibus convallis augue. Etiam vitae fringilla erat. Curabitur ornare tristique justo, eget vulputate elit pellentesque ac. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi molestie mattis turpis vitae lacinia. Mauris viverra odio non purus ornare, non aliquam tellus volutpat. Maecenas feugiat faucibus magna, eu feugiat purus mollis ac. Sed vestibulum ac velit sit amet viverra. Etiam semper laoreet est, vel maximus ligula imperdiet vel. Pellentesque posuere orci magna, eget luctus nulla vulputate ac. Nunc nec eleifend libero, eu consequat velit.
>                 </p>
>                 <br>
>                 <p>
>                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas libero nulla, tristique a neque a, pharetra iaculis justo. Duis velit purus, volutpat ac nulla at, dapibus convallis augue. Etiam vitae fringilla erat. Curabitur ornare tristique justo, eget vulputate elit pellentesque ac. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi molestie mattis turpis vitae lacinia. Mauris viverra odio non purus ornare, non aliquam tellus volutpat. Maecenas feugiat faucibus magna, eu feugiat purus mollis ac. Sed vestibulum ac velit sit amet viverra. Etiam semper laoreet est, vel maximus ligula imperdiet vel. Pellentesque posuere orci magna, eget luctus nulla vulputate ac. Nunc nec eleifend libero, eu consequat velit.
>                 </p>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>     <!-- /.container -->
> </section
> ```

The question is, why is my code not working? Also i should add, im using the bootstrap framework.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I may be missing something but do you mean after the user has scrolled to the top of the div? If so, use offset().top instead of height()

Comment: i added the html. Sorry bout that.

Comment: also offset().top() isn't working either for some reason :(

Answer (score 0):

ok, i dont know if this will help anyone, but i've finally found the solution. The trick i guess is to just use an empty css class

> .right-slide {
>   }

and a sort of place holder class which will be used to style the content of whats going to be inside that "right-slide" class. For me, i used

> .place-holder {
>       display: inline-block;
>       margin-left: 40%;
>       opacity: 0.01;
>   }

Afterwards, you assign the empty ".right-slide" class to your header tag, and then within that header tag, use a "span" class which will use the "place-holder" class. So it should look something like this

```
 <h3 class="right-slide"><span class="place-holder">Contact Number</span></h3>
```

and for the javascript, i animated the "marginLeft" which went kind of like this

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>     $(window).scroll(function(){
>         var divs_width = $('.right-slide').width(); 
>         var spans_width = $('.place-holder').width();
>         var aTop = $('.right-slide').height();
>         var right_margin = divs_width - spans_width;
>         if($(this).scrollTop()>=aTop){
>             $(".place-holder").animate({"marginLeft": "0%", 'opacity': '1'}, "slow");
>         }
>     });
> });
> ```

I did it for each of the header tags that i chose to slide from the right to the left. I still kind of new to web development, JQuery and stuff, but this was the solution for me and hope it can help other too.